# I amtrying to build redhawk version 3 on Rocky Linux but the REDHAWK dependency packages are not found

Tags: redhawksdr

I am trying to build REDHAWK on rocky linux since CentOS is going away but if I try to use:
sudo yum groupinstall "REDHAWK Development".
or
sudo yum groupinstall "REDHAWK Runtime".
both return "not found".
I am using Rocky 9.3.  Is it too new and the group is not yet available?  Do I need to go back to 8?  Rocky 9 was released in Jun 2022.  Rocky is supposed to be completely compatible with RHEL but perhaps there are different repositories?

Does Redhawk have a plan for what distro to recommend in future?

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot make these two steps from the users manual work, but reading further I see that it tells how to download all or most of the required rpms from their own repo including ones that they apparently modified from the official versions in the regular repos, so I now have them.